# Web scraping tables with BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

For some reason I'm not able to retrieve a table I am after on this [page](https://www.basketball-reference.com/boxscores/201910220LAC.html)

The table is the one titled "Line Score", below is the HTML for it:

```
<table class="suppress_all sortable stats_table now_sortable" id="line_score" data-cols-to-freeze="1"><thead><tr>
<th>&nbsp;</th>
<th colspan="5">Scoring</th>
</tr></thead><caption>Line Score Table</caption><tbody>
<tr class="thead" data-row="0">
<th>&nbsp;</th>
<th>1</th>
<th>2</th>
<th>3</th>
<th>4</th>
<th>T</th>
</tr>
<tr data-row="1">
<td><a href="/teams/LAL/2020.html">LAL</a></td>
<td class="center">25</td>
<td class="center">29</td>
<td class="center">31</td>
<td class="center">17</td>
<td class="center"><strong>102</strong></td>
</tr>
<tr data-row="2">
<td><a href="/teams/LAC/2020.html">LAC</a></td>
<td class="center">22</td>
<td class="center">40</td>
<td class="center">23</td>
<td class="center">27</td>
<td class="center"><strong>112</strong></td>
</tr>

</tbody></table>
```

My code is below:

```
import requests as r
import bs4 as bs

link = "https://basketball-reference.com/boxscores/201910220LAC.html"
resp = r.get(link)

soup = bs.BeautifulSoup(resp.content, 'lxml')

table = soup.find('table', {'class':'suppress_all sortable stats_table now_sortable'})

print table
```

I want to use the data in `<tr data-row="1"> and <tr data-row="2">` later elsewhere.

I'm sure this is easy but I just can't wrap my head around it, any assistance is much appreciated.

Thanks,
Louis

Comment: I think the content of resp isn't html, can you print it out to check

Comment: If you look at the page source, you can see that the table is in a comment. You can search for similar questions where the data needs to be scraped from a comment.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/46428197/7832176

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34673851/extracting-text-between-html-comments-with-beautifulsoup

Answer (score 0):

```
from selenium import webdriver
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from selenium.webdriver.firefox.options import Options
import time
import pandas as pd

options = Options()
options.add_argument('--headless')

driver = webdriver.Firefox(options=options)
driver.get("https://www.basketball-reference.com/boxscores/201910220LAC.html")
time.sleep(2)
soup = BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source, 'html.parser')

df = pd.read_html(driver.page_source)[18:19]

print(df)
```

Output:

```
[  Unnamed: 0  Scoring  Scoring.1  Scoring.2  Scoring.3 Scoring.4
0        NaN        1          2          3          4         T
1        LAL       25         29         31         17       102
2        LAC       22         40         23         27       112]
```